# Resolving a private hostname within a lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I've encountered problems with Lambda not being able to resolve the url like http://example.com:1234

I have to use the IP instead. I'm wondering how do I ensure that the url can be resolved, especially when the url I'm using is private. All google researches point me to Route 53, but there's no explanation on how exactly this should be done.

For more clarity:

1. All I'm doing is using the Python `requests` and calling my elasticsearch to insert some data:

   `response = requests.post(es_url, data=some_data, timeout=some_timeout)`

where `es_url` is `<ip>:9200/some_index/some_type/`.

I want to change `ip` to a human-readable domain like `my_es.example.com` which works in my EC2 instance but I cannot resolve this name in lambda function.

2. I believe I have my lambda function already connected to a VPC. I don't care about accessing public IP's. All I need is to access my ES which resides in the same VPC. Unless my setting is incorrect?

Answer (score 10):

It works fine for me.

I did the following:

- Created a new VPC using the **VPC Wizard** (Public & Private Subnets, NAT Gateway)
- Created a **Lambda function** (shown below) without a VPC connection
- Tested -- it **successfully resolved the domain name**
- Configured the Lambda function to use the **private subnet** in the new VPC
- Tested -- successful again
- Launched an **ElastiCache server** in the private subnet
- Changed the Lambda function to instead resolve the **DNS name of the ElastiCache server** -- Success!

This is the Lambda (Python 3.6) function I used:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    import socket

    data = socket.gethostbyname_ex('google.com')
    print (data)
    return
```

That worked with no VPC setting and also with the VPC configured to the private subnet.

I then ran it again with the name of the ElastiCache server:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    import socket

    data = socket.gethostbyname_ex('stack.b155ae.0001.apse2.cache.amazonaws.com')
    print (data)
    return
```

It returned:

```
('stack.b155ae.0001.apse2.cache.amazonaws.com', [], ['10.0.1.168'])
```

So, resolution of an ElastiCache name from Lambda seems to work fine.

Your problem must lie with your Lambda or VPC configuration (did you change DHCP Options?).

Comment: DHCP Options Set required to point Lambda functions at AWS Managed AD DNS servers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure the Lambda in your vpc to access the private hosted zone.